What might be causing the appearance of random contacts from Contacts app inside a Mac Safari window?
Twice I've noticed contact names from my Contacts app appear randomly on screen within a my Mac Safari window (18.1.1) (not while filling out a field in a form, for example) on my Mac (Apple M2, Sequoia 15.1.1). What may be causing this and what might I do to resolve it?
My main concern is that this could be caused by a virus or my Mac being accessed remotely without my permission. I have run scans the free versions of both AVG Antivirus and Malwarebytes, but neither have turned up viruses.

"My main concern is that this could be caused by a virus or my Mac being accessed remotely without my permission" - there is zero indication for this in your question. And the broader question "What might be causing ..." is not a security question, i.e. off-topic here. Try [apple.se].

If you've run two malware scans and found nothing, then it likely isn't malware. Causing weird, nonsensical output on screen is not what malware does. That's the OS's job. Can you describe how these name appear in more detail? Do they appear in their own window? As Tooltip/hints? Within a text field? On a particular website?
Ideally, a screenshot would be useful, though you might want to obscure the names, while still leaving enough information to show us what's going on.

To prevent Safari from suggesting information from the Contacts app, disable AutoFill in Settings > AutoFill by turning off "Using information from my contacts".

The names appear at an apparently random spot on the screen, in white letters with black around them, and then disappear after a one to three seconds.

First, I urge you to remove all so-called "antivirus" software, as it is all worse than useless on a Mac. That said, how reproducible is this behavior? If you can't reproduce it at will, how often does it happen?

I am not able to reproduce it. It has happened 2 or 3 times over the past month. Off-topic but why is antivirus software is useless on Mac and what do you recommend to prevent viruses/malware on Mac?

Briefly, (1) it doesn't work, and may give you a false sense of security that increases the risk; (2) it's intrusive and causes problems on its own; (3) macOS has built-in protections against malware that are at least as good as anything you can install; and (4) the only real protection is good computing hygiene, such as using only software from trustworthy sources. As for the topic of this thread, it will be almost impossible to chase down if you can't reproduce it and it happens only rarely. It's certainly not caused by malware or remote access.

Thank you @LincDavis. That is really helpful!
